# How can I do a map in a json file that have a key that have an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

All good?
I'm blocked from doing a function and I can't unlock it in any way
I had already done this function in vue but when trying to replicate it in react.js with typescript, I just can't do it and I really need some help
I have a JSON that contains some information
The JSON is in something similar to the following code

```js
[
  {
    "title": "jane",
    "date": "2023/01/02",
    "changes": [
      {
        "type": "new",
        "content": "blue"
      },
      {
        "type": "new",
        "content": "blue"
      },
      {
        "type": "new",
        "content": "blue"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to access the type and content values ​​that are inside changes but I can't find a way to do that. I'm making a map in JSON file and I managed to access title and date with some ease but the changes presents an error, saying that it cannot be assigned to the ReactNode

```js
import ChangeLogs from "@/records.json"

export default function Home() {
    
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>System Modification</h1>

      {ChangeLogs.map((changeLog) => {
        return <div>
            {changeLog.version}
            <br></br>
            {changeLog.date}
            <br></br>
            //{changeLog.changes} -> here is the problem
        </div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

ED: With the help of dimitrydwhite comment I managed to map the object correctly but I can't use it in the home function. I also tried to create a function outside and call it inside the component but without success

I made a few attempts and will put them below

```js
First attempt

function MapChangeLog() {
  const change = ChangeLogs.map((changeLog) => {
    return (
      <>
        {changeLog.version}
        {changeLog.date}
        {changeLog.changes?.map((change) => {
          {
            change.description;
          }
          {
            change.type;
          }
        })}
      </>
    );
  });
}

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Mudanças no sistema</h1>

      //<MapChangeLog/> -> Module 'MapChangeLog' cannot be used as a JSX component. Your 'void' return type is not a valid JSX element.

      {ChangeLogs.map((changeLog) => {
        return <div>
            {changeLog.version}
            <br/>
            {changeLog.date}
            <br/>
        </div>
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
Secound attempt

export default function Home() {

    const change = ChangeLogs.map((changeLog) => {
        return (
          <>
            {changeLog.version}
            {changeLog.date}
            {changeLog.changes?.map((change) => {
                {change.description}
                {change.type}
            })}
          </>
        );
      });
}

In this case, nothing is printed in my window
```

```js
Third attempt

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Mudanças no sistema</h1>

      {ChangeLogs.map((changeLog) => {
        return <div>
            {changeLog.version}
            <br/>
            {changeLog.date}
            <br/>
            {changeLog.changes?.map((change) => {
                {change.description}
                {change.type}
                //The type 'void[] | undefined' cannot be assigned to type 'ReactNode'.
  //Type 'void[]' cannot be assigned to type 'ReactNode'.
    //Type 'void[]' cannot be assigned to type 'ReactFragment'.
      //The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
            })}
        </div>
      })}
    </>
  );
}

In this case, i receive the error and changeLog.changes is not printed
```

I really don't have the slightest idea why I'm not able to print this changelog.changes information on the screen and need some help

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Each entry for "changes" is an array, so you will want to call .map on that as well, for example: {changeLog.changes.map(({ type, content }) => <span>{type}: {content}</span>)}

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it helped me to unlock how to do it in code. It's still not working, when I enter it in the home function, I get an error: `The type 'void[] | undefined' cannot be assigned to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'void[]' cannot be assigned to type 'ReactNode'.
    Type 'void[]' cannot be assigned to type 'ReactFragment'.` I tried to put it in a function outside and then call this function inside Home but I believe I'm doing something wrong because it's not working. I edited the question to show my attempts.

Comment: @Letícia you forgot to return most likely, show your last try